# How do I have a dropdown select list for an entity reference?

Tags: 8, entities

For Drupal 8, the entity reference field displayed in form is a textfield with auto-complete feature for you to select the entity, is it possible to have it be dropdown select list instead? I have tried using views as the reference method to check the possible solution, but without luck, someone can help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. Drupal 8 does it out of the box as D7. The only difference is you can now choose the *widget* for any field in the **Manage form display** tab of a entity type.

E.g. Try changing the widget of the entity reference field - Tags - for article content type from `/admin/structure/types/manage/article/form-display`